# Маршрут на яндекс картах 2.0

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api, javascript

Делаю карту с маршрутом, но метка по умолчанию должна стоять, а при вводе улицы и клике на кнопку - прокладываться маршрут.

Скрипт стопориться тут:  `map.geoObjects.add(route);`

Вот весь скрипт:

```
    <script>
      var map, mapRoute;

      ymaps.ready(init);

        function init () {
            var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                    center: [55.76, 37.64], 
                    zoom: 12
                }),
                myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.907228, 31.260503], {
                    balloonContentHeader: "МХЦ на Пресне"
                });

            map.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        }

      function createRoute() {
        if (mapRoute) {
          map.geoObjects.remove(mapRoute);
        }

        var routeFrom = document.getElementById('route-from').value;
        var routeTo = document.getElementById('route-to').value;

        ymaps.route([routeFrom, routeTo], {mapStateAutoApply:true}).then(
          function(route) {
            map.geoObjects.add(route);
            document.getElementById('route-length').innerHTML = 'Длина маршрута = ' + route.getHumanLength();
            mapRoute = route;
          },
          function(error) {
            alert('Невозможно построить маршрут');
          }
        );
      }
</script>

   <div>От: <input type="text" id="route-from" value="Москва, Белорусский вокзал" /></div>
<input type="hidden" id="route-to" value="Москва, ул. 1905 года, д. 7, стр. 1" />    <div><input type="submit" value="Построить маршрут" onclick="createRoute();" /></div>
```

Comment: все правильно, только проверьте, где у вас input type="hidden" id="route-to", может, текстовый, а не скрытое?

Comment: Нет, все с инпутами нормально. Маршрут строит на ура, проблема начинается, когда я пытаюсь поставить метку до построения маршрута.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция оказалась вне карты и не смогла обратиться к геообъектам.

Стоило вместить весь код внутрь **function init ()**, а нажатие кнопки отслеживать уже внутри скрипта, назначив в этом случае для кнопки **id="route"**:

```
document.getElementById("route").addEventListener("click", createRoute);
```

Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/m69xf037/

*Но вообще сейчас уже стоит использовать актуальную версию API Яндекс.Карт - 2.1 с соответствующим [примером](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_panel_control) в качестве основы.*